# Difficult dynamic CSS layout

Tags: html, css, dynamic, responsive-design

I am trying to make the following layout

```
-----------------------
|Header               |
-----------------------
|A| B                 |
| |                   |
| |                   |
| |                   |
| |                   |
| |                   |
| |                   |
-----------------------
|Footer               |
-----------------------
```

Where the following applies:

- The header and footer stays in place with a fixed height, and full viewport width
- A has remaining available height, width can be changed dynamically
- B takes remaining available height and width. Reduces width when A is made wider and vice versa
- B never flows to next line, no matter how wide the contents. (Instead a scrollbar).

I have tried a lot of table-row based positioning, and searched for similar qustions here on stackoverflow, but have not yet found any solution that works 100%.

Leaving the header and footer out of it, here is some CSS I have tried (B flows below A when making the browser window small, and the toolbar is 100% of the entire window - too high):

```
div#A {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    width: 3.5em;
}

div#A.open {
    width: auto;
}

div#B {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 700px;
    float: left;
    overflow:scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Another approach (better, but B still flows below A instead of getting scrollbars):

```
div#wrapper {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

div#A {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    width: 3.5em;
}

div#A.open {
    width: auto;
}

div#content {
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 600px;
    float: left;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: I think your question is reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

**Html**

```
<header></header>
<main>
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

> - The header and footer stays in place with a fixed height, and full viewport width

```
//css
header, footer {
  width: 5%; //fixed width that stay in place with a fixed height
}
```

> - A has remaining available height, width can be changed dynamically

```
//css
main {
    width: 100%;
}
main #a {
   float: left;
   height: 100%;
   width: 30%; //can be any width
}
```

> - B takes remaining available height and width. Reduces width when A is made wider and vice versa

```
/*#b will automatically take the rest of main!
because it has overflow:hidden */
#b {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

> - B never flows to next line, no matter how wide the contents. (Instead a scrollbar).

Here i'm not sure what you want so the fiddle is lacking this part.
Do you want an ----> or
-|
-|
-|
-|
▼
Scrollbar? 1. 
Replace `overflow:hidden;`
with `overflow-x: scroll;`
or `overflow-y: scroll;`
or `overflow: auto` for both ways
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/0g2uhqrs/4/) for example :)

Comment: Thanks. Can't make this work fully. Adding a div to B in the fiddle overlays it over A. Also it doesn't look like I can control the widths as needed.

Comment: @DennisThrysøe thanks for pointing it out! i found the error the overflow is on the parent not the actual selector and the width needs to be auto :P

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>

         #header
        {
            height:10%;
            width:100%;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        #footer
        {
            height:10%,
            width:100%;
            background-color:red;
            clear:left
        }
        #A
        {
            display:inline-block;
            float:left;
            height: 80%;
            width: 5em;
            background-color:green;
        }
        #B
        {
            display:inline-block
            float:left;
            height:80%;
            background-color:blue;
            overflow: scroll;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="A">A</div>
    <div id="B">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec imperdiet ipsum, in dapibus nulla. Aenean iaculis lorem urna, at mattis metus ultricies ac. Aliquam sodales rhoncus metus, vitae fermentum ligula ornare nec. Nunc velit justo, ornare nec nulla eget, laoreet lobortis dui. Cras blandit odio dolor, a maximus nisl maximus a. Praesent nunc diam, euismod a iaculis vitae, mattis sed quam. Integer et luctus magna. Vivamus elementum arcu in leo suscipit, at aliquet arcu eleifend. Nunc tincidunt purus non orci feugiat tempor. In dapibus velit sapien, sed egestas erat lobortis sed. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed non efficitur erat. Nullam iaculis id tellus vel rutrum. Donec porta ultricies vestibulum. Phasellus congue enim ante, vitae posuere augue ornare vitae.
        <br />
        <br />Pellentesque dolor mi, ullamcorper non odio et, tincidunt rhoncus dolor. Maecenas cursus est nec sem varius fringilla. Praesent tempor sit amet est eget convallis. Nunc tempor tempus mollis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus sagittis sodales posuere. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas ac lacinia felis. Fusce ultrices semper erat id imperdiet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin quis blandit orci. Vivamus pretium viverra ligula ac posuere. Vestibulum commodo, ante sed tempus lobortis, urna est porttitor dui, at dignissim massa nunc sed urna.
        <br />
        <br />Donec dictum lacus nec libero accumsan, auctor egestas metus sollicitudin. Nam pellentesque, ante quis lacinia tristique, sem dolor imperdiet mi, ornare consectetur tortor dui in mauris. Nulla facilisi. In sed dolor augue. Nulla ullamcorper felis vitae leo posuere posuere sit amet sed dui. Duis iaculis lorem porttitor risus iaculis congue. Mauris malesuada iaculis sapien vitae pulvinar. Nunc ut ipsum nibh. Aliquam vehicula quam eget malesuada lacinia. Curabitur eget magna ut erat pellentesque mattis sit amet eget ante. Cras et auctor felis. Nam justo diam, iaculis vel ligula sed, placerat lobortis lectus. Nulla dui enim, interdum eu posuere vel, sollicitudin non mauris.
        <br />
        <br />Morbi sit amet ultricies erat, vitae pharetra orci. Maecenas id lacus vestibulum, pellentesque ex eget, sollicitudin velit. Maecenas ultricies facilisis efficitur. Phasellus elementum tortor at ex convallis, in imperdiet nisi vulputate. Cras arcu tortor, faucibus et mattis vitae, aliquet vel ante. Nulla nec ipsum quis ex blandit elementum. In aliquam, elit ac aliquet faucibus, orci turpis tincidunt tortor, id suscipit erat urna at elit. Donec magna purus, vestibulum id erat vitae, iaculis sodales sapien.
        <br />
        <br />Quisque malesuada nunc vitae augue volutpat laoreet. Nulla egestas, nisi et fermentum congue, tortor neque finibus tellus, vel vulputate tellus tellus ut sapien. Integer fringilla posuere tellus ac mattis. Integer eget ultricies est. Aenean bibendum sapien vitae leo euismod vehicula. Curabitur venenatis ipsum quis porttitor facilisis. Morbi tincidunt condimentum urna, vitae pretium lorem pretium finibus. Vivamus volutpat erat nec tortor convallis mollis. Donec gravida orci ut elementum fringilla. Suspendisse fermentum, turpis id dapibus finibus, leo nulla suscipit sem, non aliquet ipsum est sit amet lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam pulvinar, erat in maximus maximus, eros velit blandit orci, id bibendum velit tortor non mi. Nulla risus tortor, semper sit amet nisi id, vestibulum efficitur augue. Ut quis ornare arcu, eu semper lectus.
        <br />
        <br />Nulla ut rhoncus orci. Duis et nulla commodo, mattis ligula imperdiet, aliquam arcu. Curabitur justo nulla, tristique sagittis convallis sed, convallis at purus. Donec urna nisi, ultrices a condimentum sed, ornare sit amet magna. Sed vel lacus eget lectus elementum efficitur nec vel velit. Sed sodales odio nec neque ornare, ac pulvinar eros tincidunt. Praesent interdum ac ligula non dictum. Vestibulum cursus hendrerit sollicitudin. Maecenas ultricies sapien viverra est aliquam, in pellentesque enim porta. Ut suscipit lorem at molestie malesuada. Aenean fermentum porta dolor, sed sagittis nisl tristique non. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut feugiat urna quam, a lacinia arcu placerat cursus. Integer lectus purus, eleifend et aliquam sed, consequat ac quam. Etiam et nisi enim. Quisque egestas pharetra erat et vehicula.
        <br />
        <br />Aenean convallis, purus at convallis vestibulum, nulla est pulvinar sem, ut varius dui elit et ligula. Donec porttitor rhoncus libero dignissim lacinia. Aenean eu nulla consectetur, mattis est ac, bibendum ante. Suspendisse vehicula nibh et mauris ornare, at finibus nulla aliquet. Aenean in scelerisque neque. Nulla quam lectus, consequat eu purus id, aliquam ultrices dui. Praesent et dolor pulvinar, imperdiet eros nec, lobortis justo. Mauris feugiat nulla a rhoncus aliquet. Cras ut imperdiet ante. Ut quis metus scelerisque, volutpat neque quis, pulvinar tortor. Nam placerat rhoncus lorem, non pharetra lectus auctor eget. Suspendisse in quam vitae augue blandit ultricies. Vivamus vulputate quam est, a pharetra erat porta eu. Quisque metus magna, porta eu euismod sed, porta sed erat. Aenean ornare, ante a scelerisque condimentum, ante velit aliquet arcu, vitae dictum nulla mi at massa. Quisque quis vestibulum velit, et placerat risus.
        <br />
        <br />Morbi cursus nibh eu ipsum mollis, non molestie leo auctor. Duis bibendum, neque eu tincidunt dignissim, nulla sem tincidunt metus, a lacinia risus libero eu nisl. Cras lobortis volutpat felis, in sollicitudin turpis tristique vel. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras velit quam, tristique sit amet felis quis, consequat finibus nunc. Vivamus tempor nunc nec nibh mollis vulputate. Mauris pulvinar nibh ac eros fermentum luctus. Ut at orci ut est luctus pellentesque a quis nisl. Nunc posuere tellus ex, in porta felis vulputate vel. Donec rutrum faucibus risus. Donec sapien dui, porta quis volutpat eu, tincidunt eu quam. Sed eleifend pellentesque magna, vel tempus enim dictum tincidunt. Vestibulum nisl lorem, commodo vel ipsum quis, semper sodales leo.
        <br />
        <br />Vestibulum leo urna, sollicitudin eget ultricies at, scelerisque a lectus. Donec tellus sem, elementum et elit eget, lacinia posuere elit. In lacus ex, vehicula sit amet lacus et, dapibus molestie mauris. Donec ac justo metus. Sed eget faucibus dolor. Mauris sollicitudin vehicula augue, nec molestie est fringilla sed. Vivamus non neque arcu. Proin rhoncus justo in ex vehicula mollis. Nam at commodo neque. Sed consequat lacinia augue, ac iaculis enim cursus vitae. Aliquam varius augue ac condimentum vehicula. Vestibulum quis eros vitae elit maximus varius non eu ipsum. Nullam mollis urna nulla, et sagittis dolor mollis sit amet. Ut ut purus ac augue laoreet facilisis ac non lectus.
        <br />
        <br />Nulla tincidunt non diam nec posuere. Phasellus sodales bibendum magna iaculis ullamcorper. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ultricies magna ac metus mollis tincidunt. Aenean dignissim egestas odio, id vestibulum ex ultricies in. Aliquam faucibus arcu eu enim maximus, vel hendrerit ipsum aliquet. Vestibulum posuere urna a tortor dapibus malesuada. Curabitur feugiat magna id dolor fringilla, quis suscipit lacus pellentesque. Pellentesque tristique sem urna, ut luctus erat mollis ut. Vivamus eget ultrices est, nec facilisis nisl. Integer cursus auctor lorem ut imperdiet. Vestibulum finibus odio sit amet sapien pulvinar egestas. Nunc tincidunt mi sed ex faucibus dictum. In sed tempor libero. Donec tortor nulla, malesuada vel urna laoreet, commodo interdum velit.</div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`overflow: scroll` gives you the scroll bar and `white-space: nowrap` takes away the word wrapping.

Comment: width:100%; for #B don,t get that as it moves the text to next line but not put the scrollbar for width. no width mentioned, don,t think 
http://jsfiddle.net/nnsp2vur/ link for this fiddle

Comment: @ZahidKhan you're right, I forgot about that requirement. I will see what I can come up with. Thanks.

Comment: @ZahidKhan I have updated the answer and the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is pretty much the same I arrived at. But when making the browser window smaller, the B div still flows below the A div. It should just become smaller (with a scrollbar) instead.

Comment: @DennisThrysøe with the code above in chrome, div B gets smaller with a scrollbar with resizing the window for me and doesn't flow below A. Are you using the same CSS as I have above?

Comment: I didn't use the 20% and 80% widths, as that is not what I need. I need a certain (em) with for A and "the rest" for B.

Comment: @DennisThrysøe I have updated the code. Add in `clear: left` to the footer, and remove the width from B. It's working for me.

Comment: Still can't get it to work properly. Maybe it's bootstrap messing with me (didn't mention that).